# How do I get email attachments (.html, .txt) to show in the sent email using Python script seen below?

Tags: python

My email shows the attachments without displaying what they are. I have  one `.txt` and five `.html` I wish to be specified. Does any one have a suggestion to fix this?

My code as follows:

```
import os
import smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

COMMASPACE = ', '

def email_main():
sender = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'xxxxxx123'
recipients = ['xxx@xxx.com', 'xxxyyy@yahoo.com']

# Create the enclosing (outer) message
outer = MIMEMultipart()
outer['Subject'] = 'VECTOR CAST AUTOMATED TEST RESULTS'
outer['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(recipients)
outer['From'] = sender
outer.preamble = 'You will not see this in a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'

# email message 
body = MIMEText('Test results attached.', 'html', 'text')  
outer.attach(body)  # add message body (text or html)

# List of attachments to email
emailfiles = ['VCAST Test Times.txt', \
         'AECP_MAIN_INTEGRATION_management_report.html', \
         'BECP_MAIN_INTEGRATION_management_report.html', \
         'SWITCH_BOARD_INTEGRATION_management_report.html', \
         'EVENT_MANAGER_INTEGRATION_management_report.html', \
         'EXTERNAL_ALARM_INTEGRATION_management_report.html']

# get the path of the folder this lives in 
attachments = [os.getcwd()]

# Add the attachments to the message
for file in attachments:
    try:
        for line in emailfiles:              
            fp = open(line , 'rb')            
            msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
            msg.set_payload(fp.read()) 
            encoders.encode_base64(msg)
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(file))

            """
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
            msg = MIMEApplication(open(file_path, "r").read(), _subtype="txt")
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=f)
            """
            outer.attach(msg)
    except:
        print("Unable to open one of the attachments. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise

composed = outer.as_string()

# Send the email
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(sender, gmail_password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
server.quit()   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email_main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
os.getcwd()
```

gives you the current directory, for example `C:\Projects\EmailTest`
So

```
[os.getcwd()]
```

gives you a list, containing one string (`C:\Projects\EmailTest`)

So the loop

```
for file in attachments:
```

is only executed once, where `file=C:\Projects\EmailTest`.

And when you finally set in the inner loop, you use `file` from the outer loop: (which is `C:\Projects\EmailTest`)

```
filename=os.path.basename(file)
```

You simply extract the folder name from file, i.e. `EmailTest`.

Im guessing you want the filename instead, stored in `emailfiles`, which in your case is `line` in the inner loop. And since it is already only the filanem, you can skip `os.path.basename`:

```
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=line)
```

Comment: Hi Kid Binary, your suggestion worked exactly as I need, my emails I send shows the attachments now. Such a simple over sight on my part thank and god bless you..